# Wifi Adapter with Antenna with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, usb, wifi

I am working on a robot remote controlled over a wifi connection.
I need a decent wifi adapter with better reception. 
Can I use the  -Edimax Wireless nLITE 3dBi High Gain USB Adapter EW-7711UAn with Raspbian ?
If so, how?

Comment: This question is very vague right now.  What do you mean by "better reception"?  What research have you done yourself?

Comment: Have you tried using a wind-surfer antenna on your wifi router/accesd point, given you know the direction/position of the robot?

Answer (score 2):

1. you should use adapter that already has linux support, preferably debian (easier to port the packages) or any other flavour of linux.
2. make sure you have an adequate power supply, hi-power wifi modules can easily consume 1-2A, so you have to aim for a 3-5A capable (or better) power supply, which are rare, but still possible to find.